# cfquery to queryExecute: if inside SQL string

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, lucee, cfexecute

what is *the best way* to do what I did in `<cfquery>` even in `queryExecute`

**cfquery**

```
<cfquery name="qry">
    SELECT * FROM tbl_products
    WHERE filed1 = 1

    <cfif structKeyExists(URL, "test")>
        AND filed2 = 2
    </cfif>

    ORDER BY id DESC
</cfquery>
```

**cfexecute**

```
<cfscript>

    sql = "
        SELECT * FROM tbl_products
        WHERE filed1 = 1
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ";

    if (structKeyExists(URL, "test")){
        sql = "
            SELECT * FROM tbl_products
            WHERE filed1 = 1
            AND filed2 = 2
            ORDER BY id DESC
        ";
    }

    qry = queryExecute(
        sql = sql
    );

</cfscript>
```

*I hope I've explained myself well...*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to build up the SQL string. Also well worth passing in the param values, so that you are protected from SQL injection. Something like:

```
<cfscript>
params = {};

sql = "
    SELECT * FROM tbl_products
    WHERE filed1 = :filed1 
";
params["filed1"] = 1;

if (structKeyExists(URL, "test")){
    sql &= "AND filed2 = :filed2 ";
    params["filed2"] = 2;
}

sql &= "ORDER BY id DESC";

queryExecute(sql, params);
</cfscript>
```

Alternatively, you can use positional parameters.

```
<cfscript>
params = [];

sql = "
    SELECT * FROM tbl_products
    WHERE filed1 = ?
";
arrayAppend(params, 1);

if (structKeyExists(URL, "test")){
    sql &= "AND filed2 = ? ";
    arrayAppend(params, 2);
}

sql &= "ORDER BY id DESC";

queryExecute(sql, params);
</cfscript>
```

This is one of the times where tags is better than script.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that I do it this way. I was hoping there was some "trick" to solve in some other "cleaner" way :D